# Perpendicular eigenvectors and symmetry

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Assume, that matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ has $n$ eigenvectors, which are all perpendicular with respect to one another. Show that $A$ is symmetric.

This was an extra question on an exam and Im curious on how one would show this?

Comment: Let $x,y$ be perpendicular eigenvectors. Then $(x,Ay)=0$, and $(x,A^ty)=(Ax,y)=0$. Try to flesh that out to a proof.

Comment: Such matrices are called normal and have $AA^T = A^TA. But symmetric matrices are only a subclass of these. Other are skew-symmetric and orthogonal matrices

Comment: You've had a sketch of a proof from me, Daniel, and an answer from Ferhat. So, how is it going for you?

Comment: Are you still here, Daniel?

Comment: Hi! Im still here. Im still trying to wrap my head around Ferhat's answer...

Answer (score 3):

Let your matrix be denoted by $A$. If your eigenvectors are perpendicular to each other, divide them to their norms and then you will get n unit orthogonal vectors which are also your eigenvectors. Then these eigenvectors can create orthogonal matrix $Q$ and we know $Q^T=Q^{-1}$. After using matrix diagonalization, you will see that $A^T=(Q^{-1}DQ)^T=(Q^TDQ)^T=Q^TDQ=Q^{-1}DQ=A$.